# Is there a Book within Skyrim that translates the Dragon Tongue?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'm aware of lore webpages dedicated to translations and education on the Dragon's Language in the game, but is there any in-game source that does something similar?

Comment: The Elder Scrolls Strategy Guide has the translations.  It's not in-game but the information from it can be found here: [Dragon Language](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Dragon_Language)

Comment: <Pokes @Mark Trapp>

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Dragon Language: Myth no More](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Dragon_Language:_Myth_no_More) is the only book I know of. The rest of the translations done online were guesswork done by various in-game dialog and pieced together by the community.

Comment: UESP link: http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Dragon_Language:_Myth_no_More

Answer (score -2):

I found a book which talked about translation of the language to English. Dragon dictionary or something?

It doesn't unlock any shouts or anything tho. 
If you want more of them. Use the strategy guide or Google a dedicated skyrim wiki.

Comment: Hey TheyShineToBright, welcome to gameing.SE! Your answer doesnt help me at all unfortunatly. I mentioned in my question that I'm looking for in-game sources of such translations or educational peices. Your answer hasn't mentioned anything of the sort, so I voted it down. If you edit your answer to include information that would pertain to my question (that Resorath hasn't already mentioned), I'll be sure to change my vote. Better luck next time!